# How to implement a WordPress Action Hook

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the All-In-One Video Player plugin and want to alter its behaviour by listening to events that the player emits and taking actions based on them.

I contacted plugin's support team and got a very good response that I'm sure would mean something to someone who understands WordPress - I'm not one of those people.

The support team suggested using the action hook `aiovg_player_footer`. It looks like I have to implement that function, but I have no idea **where** to write that code. Is there a specific file that I need to create / update in order to get implement this function.

My function will need to alter the HTML that the plugin produces. Is this just a case of doing something like

`echo '<script>console.log("helo");</script>'` ?

Comment: You have to write a plugin / theme in order to implement a hook. The convention would be to implement a plugin if it's not ui related

Comment: The easiest way is to write it in the `functions.php` located in the root of your theme folder.

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves : If i put in the theme will it still be found by the plugin? I tried that last night and I had no evidence that it was called - but it could be that the function was called, but just didn;t do what I was hoping for. If I want to write <SCRIPT> tags, can I use the method I show in the question?

Comment: @DaveH yes, it will. Of course, you should provide more information on how to implement that hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following code in `functions.php` file located in the root of your theme directory:

```
function so61638829_aiovg_player_footer()
{
   // Do something
}
add_action('aiovg_player_footer', 'so61638829_aiovg_player_footer');
```